# How to import exception for use in clojure test

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to make a test with `thrown?` as described [here](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html#clojure.test/with-test), but I get the error below.

```
   7 | (deftest exception-test
   8 |   (is (thrown? ArithmeticException (/ 1 0))) 
----------------------^---------------------------------------------------------
Use of undeclared Var demo.app-test/ArithmeticException
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   9 |   )
```

I guess that I have to import it somehow, but haven't been able to figure it out. The namespace looks like this:

```
(ns demo.app-test
  (:require [cljs.test :refer (deftest is)]))
```

I'm using [shadow-cljs](https://github.com/thheller/shadow-cljs).

Comment: Javascript and so CLJS has no `ArithmethicException` - this test there most likely is taken from java/clj. Dividing by zero in javascript gives you "infinity". There is a clear difference between clj and cljs what they can do and use (there are ways to use the same source code for both platforms, but you have to deal with specific platform things).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript and so ClojureScript has no `ArithmethicException` - this test there
most likely is taken from a Java/Clojure example.  Dividing by zero in
JavaScript gives you "infinity" (no exception thrown).

There is a clear difference between Clojure and ClojureScript what they can do
and use.  There are ways to use the same source code (e.g. `cljc`) for both
platforms, but you have to deal with specifics to the platform yourself (there
are reader macros in cljc to help with that).

Note: you have access to the ArithmethicException in CLJS if you are writing
macros, which again are just Clojure running at compile time, but that is just
a nuance to the "will never work" answer.